# How to hot-reload resources inside jar with maven jetty plugin?

Tags: maven-jetty-plugin

I use the maven jetty plugin

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</plugin>
```

I have webapp with some other maven modules all in the same project.
When I do the mvn jetty:run all my ressources jsp, template are hot deployed once I save them. But this work only for the resources under the webapp folder.

Is is possible to include on the hot deploy the ressources contained in the other maven module/jar?